# Shift Register Design using Structural Verilog outputs X

Tags: verilog, flip-flop, mux

I am designing a shift register using hierarchical structural Verilog.  I have designed a D flip flop and an 8 to 1 mux that uses 3 select inputs.  I am trying to put them together to get the full shift register, but my output only gives "XXXX" regardless of the select inputs.

Flip Flop Code

```
module D_Flip_Flop(
input D,
input clk,
output Q, Q_bar
);
 
 wire a,b,c,d;
 
 nand(a,D,b);
 nand(b,a,clk,d);
 nand(c,a,d);
 nand(d,c,clk);
 nand(Q,d,Q_bar);
 nand(Q_bar,b,Q);   

endmodule
```

8 to 1 Mux

```
module Mux8to1(
input [2:0]S,
 input A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,
output Out
);
 
 wire a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
 
 and(a, A,~S[2],~S[1],~S[0]);
 and(b, B,~S[2],~S[1],S[0]);
 and(c, C,~S[2],S[1],~S[0]);
 and(d, D,~S[2],S[1],S[0]);
 and(e, E,S[2],~S[1],~S[0]);
 and(f, F,S[2],~S[1],S[0]);
 and(g, G,S[2],S[1],~S[0]);
 and(h, H,S[2],S[1],S[0]);
 
 or(Out, a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h);


endmodule
```

Hierarchical Combination of the Two

```
module shiftRegister_struct(
input clk,
input [2:0]S,
input [3:0]L,
output reg [3:0]V
);
 
 wire a,b,c,d;
 wire V_bar[3:0];
 
 Mux8to1 stage3(S[2:0],V[3],V[0],V[2],1'b0,V[2],V[3],V[2],L[3],a);
 Mux8to1 stage2(S[2:0],V[2],V[3],V[1],V[3],V[1],V[3],V[1],L[2],b);
 Mux8to1 stage1(S[2:0],V[1],V[2],V[0],V[2],V[1],V[2],V[1],L[1],c);
 Mux8to1 stage0(S[2:0],V[0],V[1],V[3],V[1],1'b0,V[1],1'b0,L[0],d);
 
 D_Flip_Flop stage3b(a,clk,V[3],V_bar[3]);
 D_Flip_Flop stage2b(b,clk,V[2],V_bar[2]);
 D_Flip_Flop stage1b(c,clk,V[1],V_bar[1]);
 D_Flip_Flop stage0b(d,clk,V[0],V_bar[0]);

end module
```

Any thoughts on what might be screwing up my output? The output is `V[3:0]`.

I should also include my test bench code:

```
module Shift_Test_Bench;

// Inputs
reg [2:0] S;
reg [3:0] L;
reg clk;

integer i;
integer j;

// Outputs
wire [3:0] V;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
shiftRegister_struct uut (
    .clk(clk),
    .S(S), 
    .L(L),
    .V(V)
);

initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    S = 7;
    L = 3;
    clk = 1;
    

    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
    #100;
    
    // Add stimulus here
    
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i = i+1)
    begin
        S = i;
        
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j = j+1)
            begin
            clk = !clk;
            #5;
            end
            
    end
            
        
    

end
  
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wiring bug in your `D_Flip_Flop` module.  When I simulated your testbench, I got compiler warnings:

```
  Implicit wire 'f' does not have any driver, please make sure this is 
  intended.

  Implicit wire 'e' does not have any driver, please make sure this is 
  intended.
```

Here are the lines:

```
 nand(Q,d,f);
 nand(Q_bar,b,e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a reset condition, either synchronous or asynchronous. Your flops have an unknown value and never reach known state because the data input is dependent on the flop output. By adding a reset to can put the flops into a known state independent of its outputs (`V`/`V_bar`).

In this case adding a synchronous is be easier. Simply add some 2-to-1 muxes and a new reset pin.

```
Mux2to1 syncrst3(a_d,a,1'b0,reset);
// ...
D_Flip_Flop stage3b(a_d,clk,V[3],V_bar[3]);
// ...
```